# passport verify isn't being called on form submit

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I am trying to use passport local, but it doesn't seem like the verify function is being called. I have console.log of a, b, and c, but none of them trigger any output. It does redirect to /failure

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;



  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function (username, password, done) {
      console.log('a')
      users.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
        console.log('b')

        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
        if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }
  ));

  app.get('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(`<form action="/login" method="post">
    <div>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Log In"/>
    </div>
</form>`);
  });

  app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/failure' }),
    function (req, res) {
      console.log('c')
      res.redirect('/');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `req.body` isn't being populated since body parser isn't being included into express.

Add `var bodyParser = require('body-parser')` and `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))` so that `req.body` is populated for passport-local

This was discovered after sticking some console.log messages `passport/lib/middleware/authenticate` to find the failure was "Missing credentials", and looking for that string in `passport-local/lib/strategy`, and finding that body was undefined, I realized that `body-parser` was missing.